# Using DateTime and an Employee count, then filling in the rest of the numbers with 0's

Tags: c#, datetime, counter

I'm trying to create a simple Employee class that increments the employee count each empolyee instance that is created.
Which is extremely simple, except I have been asked to create the employee number that should be constructed by using the current year (using a DateTime object) and the current employee count padded with leading zeroes, so that the employee number is always 8 characters long, e.g. If the tenth employee was created in 2013, the employee number would be 20130010. You do not have to reset the employee counter every year.

now I've done the whole

```
string year = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

and incremented the empoylee count,
but I'm so confused as to how to fill in the remaining gaps with 0's.

Any help would be appreciated as this is so frustrating because its probably an extremely easy solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

it should be much simple.

but do use year and not complete date.

code snippet below:

```
string id = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + 10.ToString("0000");
```

Comment: you just need to change 10 as dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly the probably you just want to add leading zeros to your number.

```
string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
int EmpNumber = 1;
string newNumber = year + EmpNumber.ToString("D4");
```

Output would be : `"20120001"`

You may see: [How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)

Comment: -1: This really doesn't do what the OP wants. Your code will pad before the year, not between year and employee number.

Comment: `but I'm so confused as to how to fill in the remaining gaps with 0's` that is in the question, and I was trying to address that

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, oh yes, that is correct, I need to do that for the employee number.  let me rectify it

Comment: But you did it wrong. Try reading the question again. He has running number 10 in the year 2013. The result should be 20130010, that is: year and 10 padded with zeros. I don't even know where your original number (which is a string) originates.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, rectified my answer. I think. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like this:

```
var employeeId = string.Format("{0}{1:D4}", DateTime.Now.Year, runningNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into the [String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx) method.

`string employeeId = string.Concat(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), (lastEmployeeId + 1).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');`

You might want to consider using an Oracle sequence or SQLServer auto_increment as you might run into threading/synchronization issues (ie two employees created at the same time and assigned the same employee id).

Also keeping track of the amount of employees should only be done as an optimization when it turns out to be necessary. If you do not have performance issues, you can get the amount of employees by using a `COUNT` (on the database or on the in memory `List<Employee>`) statement.

Keeping track of both the list of employees and the number of employees is in violation of the [Single Source of Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth). I promise you that once things get more complicated you will run into trouble: At some point the two counts will (for some reason) be different...